# Signing an existing Android APK with a new certificate and releasing on Google play

Tags: android, google-play, apk, sha256, sha1

So we currently have an existing keystore which we use to sign our APKs and release onto Google Play. But the certificate in the keystore is using a certificate which as been signed using SHA1RSA algorithm and now we have started seeing warnings since SHA1 is a weak algo and is now obsolete.

We have already requested for a new certificate this time signed using Sha256RSA authentication, and once we receive the same we are planning to create a new keystore and sign our APK using the new keystore.

Now the main question is, once this newly signed APK has been deployed to google play in prod,

1. Would the users having the previous version of the app still be able to access the application?
2. Would we need to do a force update, so that all users will be able to access our application without any issues?

Comment: Changing the signing key would AFAIK require [Key rotation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0#apk-key-rotation) which  requires at minimum Android 9+. However the APK signature format does support multiple signatures. Not sure what happens if you start signing your release APK two times, with the old SHA-1 based cert/key and additionally with the new one.

Comment: Note that you don't need to request an code signing certificate for signing Android apps, you can simply generate a new self-signed one. Of course you can buy one from a trust center, but there is no advantage and the number of publishers that do not use self-signed certs is very low. The only one I know is Amazon which uses a commercial code-signing certificate.